# Parasitic inductance when probing high frequency signals with MMCX connectors?

Tags: rf, switch-mode-power-supply, boost

I am using an oscilloscope to probe some high-frequency circuits (a SMPS). On my circuit board, I have installed some MMCX connectors to connect my probes to. These MMCX connectors have a short pigtail connected to an SMA-BNC adapter, which then connects to my BNC - scope probe adapter, the pigtail length is about 15cm.

These MMCX connectors are on the opposite side of the board and connect to the gate input of the FET I'm reading the signals of. They are directly underneath the gate drive signal and have a very short path to the gate and ground. It's on a 4 layer PCB, but the internal layers have a keepout zone.

If I read the signal from the MMCX connector, there appears to be significant parasitic inductance that heavily modifies the gate drive signal as it appears on the oscilloscope; I'd imagine substantial efficiency losses and error, which I'm not seeing.

If I read the same signal from the side of the board with the FET using a scope ground spring clip, the signal appears fairly typical of a high-frequency gate signal (minus the collapse).

Which is likely to be the more reliable signal? Is it possible that the 50ohm pigtail and connectors are causing a lot of this parasitic inductance and reflections between the source and the scope, and if so, how is the best way to measure these frequencies with 50ohm hardware? Signals pictured for reference

**How do you reliably setup and measure high frequency signals using passive scope probes and 50 ohm RF hardware?**

**GATE Through MMCX Connector**
[image: FET Gate with MMCX Connector]

**GATE Through Spring Clip**
[image: FET Gate with Spring Clip]

Comment: Did you put your scope into 50 ohm termination mode to match the 50 ohm cable? Since the amplitude in the images is the same I think not. Without impedance matching you will see reflections given the nanoseconds rise time of the signal and relatively long cables.